# Select with formatted string into object using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to select into an object using Linq where one of the elements is a number and I want to format it as a string on the fly.  I want to create a specific description text including some of the data from other columns.  If you look at the select-sentence, I´m trying to format the string as Currency with two decimals, this is not working.  How should I do this correctly?

```
var stuff = from obj in _dbc.Stuff
 where
     SqlMethods.Like(obj.SEGMENT2, "0023") &&
     SqlMethods.Like(obj.SEGMENT4, "1243") 
 group obj by new
     {
         obj.SEGMENT1
     }
 into g
 select new StuffObject
 {
     Item = g.Key.SEGMENT1,
     Description = 
         string.Format("{0:C2}", g.Sum(p => p.VALUE == null ? 0 : p.VALUE.Value))  //<-- This is not working for me
         + "<br/>" + g.Min(p => p.DESCRIPTION),
     DeCode = g.Min(p => p.SEGMENT2),
     CeCode = g.Min(p => p.SEGMENT4),
     QTY = g.Sum(p => p.QUANTITY == null ? 0 : (int)p.QUANTITY),
     Cost = g.Sum(p => p.VALUE == null ? 0 : (double)p.VALUE)
 };
```

**Btw, the error code I´m receiveing is:**
`System.InvalidOperationException: Could not translate expression .... abbreviated ...into SQL and could not treat it as a local expression.`

My StuffObject class as it is now (I haven´t tried @Grundy answer yet):

```
public class StuffObject
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string DeCode { get; set;}
    public string CeCode { get; set; }
    public int QTY{ get; set; }
    public double Cost { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: **PLease specify what exactly happens: "Not working" alone won't give any clue about what you did wrong**. That said, I bet there is a `NULL` value in your DB. In this case, you don't have to compare with `null` but with `DBNull.Value` : `g.Sum(p => p.VALUE != DBNull.Value ? 0 : p.VALUE.Value))`

Comment: In your sample, can you remove all the unnecessary code? If you remove the unnecessary code, it will make it easier to focus on, and also may shed light on the answer.

Comment: I don't think its a DBNull problem, otherwise p.VALUE.Value would fail. p.VALUE is clearly a nullable primitive.

Comment: Yes, p.VALUE is a nullable primitive.  I´ll edit the code and remove unneccessary code, one moment.

Comment: Ok, I cleaned it up a bit

Comment: can you provide `StuffObject` declaration? can you change it?

Comment: Do you mean if I can change the StuffObject declaration @Grundy?  Sorry, I didn´t catch that last sentence (my english)

Comment: @gardarvalur try see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ can't translate `string.Format` to SQL, so you need get rid of it.
You can change `StuffObject` like

```
public class StuffObject{
    ....
    private decimal sumValue;
    private decimal description;
    public string Description {
        get{
            return string.Format("{0:C2}<br/>{1:C2}", sumvalue,description);
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

and then change LINQ query like this

```
....
select new StuffObject
{
    Item = g.Key.SEGMENT1,
    description =g.Min(p => p.DESCRIPTION),
    sumValue =g.Sum(p => p.VALUE == null ? 0 : p.VALUE.Value),
    DeCode = g.Min(p => p.SEGMENT2),
    CeCode = g.Min(p => p.SEGMENT4),
    QTY = g.Sum(p => p.QUANTITY == null ? 0 : (int)p.QUANTITY),
    Cost = g.Sum(p => p.VALUE == null ? 0 : (double)p.VALUE)
};
```

Comment: Thank you @Grundy, I´ll give this a try and I will let you know in a bit.

Comment: @gardarvalur possibly you need use another type for field `sumValue` like `long`, `int` etc

Comment: @gardarvalur I'm confused with the field `description`, it's a string or a number?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @Grundy, I´ll update my question with the declaration of StuffObject class.  Yes Description is a string.